# Use Powershell's BeginInvoke() and EndInvoke() in async way

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

Is there a way to use Powershell's BeginInvoke() and EndInvoke() in a real async way. That's, I just call BeginInvoke() and then forget instead of using EndInvoke to wait for the return or result. I like EndInvoke to be a callback function called automatically when BeginInvoke() finishes. 
[The example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.endinvoke%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is actually a sync one.

How can I use BeginInvoke() and EndInvoke() in a real async way? Thanks.

Comment: I thought BeginInvoke() is itself an Async way. Inoke() is the Sync one...

Answer (score 8):

You should probably use [`BeginInvoke` overload with `AsyncCallback` argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182439(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm not easily understanding how to do that within PowerShell. By any chance do you have any links to an example? I'm really surprised that doc is missing an example.